# How to import Lodash with TypeScript and Webpack without overwriting existing _ var

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, lodash

I'm creating a module for an application that uses Lodash 3. In that module I'd like to use Lodash 4. The new module is written in TypeScript and packed with Webpack.

I thought that if I do `import * as _ from 'lodash'` in the new module it would not overwrite the window._ but it does. I noticed this issue on GitHub https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1798 and it looks like my issue and it seemed to be resolved in 4.14.0. I'm using Lodash 4.15.0

Is there something special that I have to do while importing Lodash in my code not to overwrite window._?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? Having a similar issue... website globally is using lodash v2, but we have a submodule that we would like to bundle with lodash v4.

Comment: @Mark Sorry but I don't think I did but it's hard to remember since it was more than 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

See [Lodash unexpectedly injects itself into global when required in subdependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981230/lodash-unexpectedly-injects-itself-into-global-when-required-in-subdependency).

Adding

```
module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/lodash\/lodash\.js/,
}
```

to my config stopped lodash from exporting itself to the window.

If you still have issues, you could look at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#noConflict although I'm not sure how well that would solve your problem.